# Changing data type in a Deedle Frame

Tags: csv, f#, type-conversion, deedle

I imported some data in a Deedle Frame, and I'm trying to convert values type in integer type.

I used the following code:

```
let myFrmK01 = Frame.ReadCsv(@"QuandlDataSample.csv", hasHeaders=true)
let myFrmK02 = myFrmK01
                |> Frame.indexRowsDate "Date"
                |> Frame.sortRowsByKey
```

Now, to convert the values type I tryed with:

```
let myFrame03 = Frame.mapValues (fun (x:float) -> (Convert.ToUInt64(x * 100.0))) myFrame02
```

and if I go to see the values of the frame with:

```
myFrame03.Item("Adj. Open").Item (DateTime(2017, 5, 3))
```

I find it is still a float.
Where I'm wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You are wrong in taking result of `Frame.Item` property for the genuine type of the column. The signature of `myFrame03.Item("Adj. Open")` is `string -> Series<DateTime,float>`, so the result of individual observation cannot be anything, but `float`.

If you use another form of `Item` property

```
myFrame03.Item("Adj. Open",DateTime(2017, 5, 3))
```

having the signature `string*DateTime -> obj` you must see that the observation is `unsigned long` as expected after you've applied
`Frame.mapValues`, indeed.

Besides, when in doubt, you can always check actual data frame column types:

```
myFrame03.ColumnTypes |> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
```

Comment: Gene, I followed your advice, and found the other form of `Item` in documentation. Thank you very much.